# I need help for discord js v13

Tags: javascript, discord.js

my code

```
function kanalbackup() {
  let guild = client.guilds.cache.get(ayarlar.guildID);
  if (!guild) return;
  if (guild) {
    guild.channels.cache.filter(kanal => kanal.deleted !== true).forEach(channel => {
      let permissionss = {};
      let sayi = Number(0);
      channel.PermissionOverwriteManager.forEach((perm) => {
        let thisPermOverwrites = {};
        perm.allow.toArray().forEach(p => {
          thisPermOverwrites[p] = true;
        });
        perm.deny.toArray().forEach(p => {
          thisPermOverwrites[p] = false;
        });
        permissionss[sayi] = {permission: perm.id == null ? guild.id : perm.id, thisPermOverwrites};
        sayi++;
      })
```

error
Channel#deleted is deprecated,
(Use `node --trace-deprecation ...` to show where the warning was created)
TypeError: channel.permissionOverwrites.forEach is not a function

Discord js upgrade error v12 to v13 ı need help

Comment: Welcome. Please see [ask] and take the [tour], then revise your post title to ask a clear, specific question. _Everyone_ who asks on this site needs help.

Answer (score -1):

Basically the function `channel.deleted` has been removed from discord.js and you can't use it anymore. Full article on this: https://github.com/discordjs/discord.js/issues/7091. You can simply remove the filter in the channel cache to solve the problem. It also appears that you haven't created a `permissionOveriteManager`, and it's spelled wrong. The code would then look like the following:

```js
function kanalbackup() {
  let guild = client.guilds.cache.get(ayarlar.guildID);
  if (!guild) return;
  if (guild) {
    guild.channels.cache.forEach(channel => {
      let permissionss = {};
      let sayi = Number(0);
      channel.permissionOverwriteManager.create().forEach((perm) => {
        let thisPermOverwrites = {};
        perm.allow.toArray().forEach(p => {
          thisPermOverwrites[p] = true;
        });
        perm.deny.toArray().forEach(p => {
          thisPermOverwrites[p] = false;
        });
        permissionss[sayi] = {permission: perm.id == null ? guild.id : perm.id, thisPermOverwrites};
        sayi++;
      })
```

Comment: A deprecation warning is just that - a warning. The actual error is a typeerror as shown in the question `TypeError: channel.permissionOverwrites.forEach is not a function`

Comment: Then it's impossible to actually solve the problem without more context on what the OC wants the code to do. I'll edit the solution to show possible fixes, but without more info, I can't provide a clear solution.